# What is the difference between Crystallize and Crystallize+?

Tags: dicey-dungeons

While playing as the Jester, I somehow managed to add a Crystallize card to my deck. I believe this was some strange interaction with the Thief card's steal ability, as Crystallize replaced my Thief. When I came to an anvil, I saw I could upgrade Crystallize to Crystallize+. However, the description on the upgraded item doesn't say anything different.

How is Crystallize+ different from Crystallize?

[image: Crystallize upgrade]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crystallize creates regular crystal weapons, while Crystallize+ creates upgraded crystal weapons.

[image: Upgraded crystal weapon]